# Problem with Financial Data

Tags: curated-data, finance

I'm following http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FinancialData.html

I get the following:

```
In[6]:= DateListLogPlot[FinancialData["^DJI", All]]
```

> During evaluation of In[6]:= DateListLogPlot::ntdt: The first argument to DateListLogPlot should be a list of pairs of dates and real values, a list of real values, or a list of several such lists. >>
>
> Out[6]= DateListLogPlot[Missing["NotAvailable"]]

```
In[8]:= FinancialData["DJI", All]
```

> During evaluation of In[8]:= FinancialData::notent: DJI is not a known entity, class, or tag for FinancialData. Use FinancialData[] for a list of entities. >>
>
> Out[8]= FinancialData["DJI", All]

```
In[9]:= FinancialData["^DJI"]
```

> Out[9]= Missing["NotAvailable"]

What's going on here? Is the DJI data unavailable somehow?

Comment: It appears it's not available right now for me either.  Other indices are working. `DateListLogPlot[FinancialData["AAPL", All]]`.

Comment: What happens if you execute `FinancialData["^DJI", "Properties"]`? `FinancialData["^DJI", All]`?

Comment: @J.M. Same thing. `Missing["NotAvailable"]`

Comment: Looks like something screwy with the API...

Comment: It would be ridicilous if historical data can only be accessed while the market is open.

Comment: Over the past several weeks lots of glitches have appeared in the curated financial data.  e.g., after markets have closed, retrieve all available data for a number of ETF's ("SPY", "TLT", others) and you often find that you get two records with the current date at the end of the list.  It appears that the originator of the curated data (Yahoo Finance?) has introduced some changes into their technology infrastructure or perhaps their data base model.  One can only hope they clean up the issue.  I don't know that we have any leverage in getting them to resolve it excepting reporting to Wolfram.

Comment: Did you have in mind some time range? Which years will do for you?

Comment: @Vitaliy: I actually don't need the data for any actual trading; I'm just playing with the API / reading documentation / complaining about things that don't work. :-)

Comment: Yahoo Finance is the data source that is used. Here is a statement on their website concerning this: http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_FIN&locale=en_US&id=SLN2332&impressions=true

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679870/yahoo-finance-csv-file-will-not-return-dow-jones-dji) at SO: **"Yahoo! Finance CSV file will not return Dow Jones (^DJI)"**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If one looks for curated data accessible from Mathematica, the `WolframAlpha` function should always be considered as an option, because it links to curated data bases with frequent continuous updating:

```
data = WolframAlpha["^DJI price history", 
         {{"HistoryDaily:Close:FinancialData", 1}, "TimeSeriesData"}, 
         PodStates -> {"HistoryDaily:Close:FinancialData__All data"}];
```

And this is basically the same plot as in the documentation:

```
DateListLogPlot[data, Filling -> 1, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

You also can access these data interactively to get the same programming syntax. This can actually teach how syntax looks in different cases:

[image]

To understand better `WolframAlpha` integration in *Mathematica* I suggest the following sources:

- [WolframAlpha function documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WolframAlpha.html)
- [Data Formats in Wolfram|Alpha tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DataFormatsInWolframAlpha.html)
- [Mathematica: Wolfram|Alpha Integration free video course](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/virtualconference/wolfram-alpha-in-mathematica/)

Comment: This is impressive. I no longer consider the $130 I spend on mathematica student edition a waste of money.

Comment: Good answer, but it *is* a workaround.Point is that FinancialData is not always trustworthy and some of its data may at unpredictable times be unavailable. Do you suggest to always skip this function and use WolframAlpha instead?

Comment: Just for the record (not anything against Sjoerd's comment) -- even if I would never use this, I'm really grateful for this answer, because I stupidly never realized I had WolframAlpha at my fingertips with Mathematica. (Silly isn't it?)

Comment: @term-rewritica Just be aware that you're limited to 100 W|A API calls/day (I think) with a student license.  I've never hit the limit, or even 10 calls for that matter, but looks like you might with your excitement ;)

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is with the data provider Yahoo!. There has been intermittent problems with Yahoo! over the past few weeks with the DJI. The workaround is `WolframAlpha[]` as described in one of the answers above.

---

(from Searke's comment)

Yahoo! is [no longer licensed to provide data downloads for the Dow Jones Index](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_FIN&locale=en_US&id=SLN2332). Since Yahoo! is (one of) the data providers used by `FinancialData[]`, `FinancialData[]` is also affected by this restriction.

Comment: Is there an official statement on their dev website? This answer would be more useful if you could link to that statement...

Comment: AFAIK XIgnite is the data provider ...or used to be.

Comment: FinancialData uses both sources for information. See this article from Yahoo about why ^DJI is no longer available.

http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_FIN&locale=en_US&id=SLN2332&impressions=true

Answer (score 1):

We have another option now: [QuandlLink](https://github.com/bajracha71/Quandl-Mathematica-QuandlLink) package. Using this package you can compute this as:

```
Needs["QuandlLink`"]

dowJonesOHLCV = 
QuandlFinancialData[ 
   "YAHOO/INDEX_DJI", 
   startDate -> "2015-01-01", 
   column -> 1 ;; 6];

TradingChart[Rest@dowJonesOHLCV, PlotLabel -> "OHLCV"]
```

[image: trading chart]