# Accessing chemical property data for specific conditions?

Tags: curated-data, chemistry

There is a wealth of data for various chemicals available through *Mathematica*. For instance:

```
ChemicalData["Water", "Density"]
(* 1000. kg/(m)^3 *)

Module[{formula = ChemicalData["Water", "Formula"],
plot = ChemicalData["Water", "MoleculePlot"]}, Labeled[plot, formula, Bottom, Frame -> True]]
```

[image]

How does one ask for **property data at specific conditions** (i.e., temperature, pressure, phase, etc.)?
I've been looking through the Wolfram [help](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChemicalData.html) and [tutorials](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseCuratedData.html), but I haven't run across this particular case.

It seems like this should be possible using queries to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=density+of+water+at+150+C+and+pressure+of+50+bar) as well, but I'd rather take advantage of native *Mathematica* functionality if it's available.

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17653/interactive-steam-tables-and-phase-diagrams-in-mathematica

Comment: The `ChemicalData` help page states: *If not otherwise specified, physical properties are given for standard temperature and pressure.* This may imply that properties for other conditions are not available.

Comment: You could try asking W|A and then convert to Mma code to see if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want here is [`ThermodynamicData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ThermodynamicData.html).  The available properties are

```
ThermodynamicData["Properties"] 

(* {"CriticalDensity", "CriticalEnthalpy", "CriticalEntropy", 
"CriticalInternalEnergy", "CriticalPressure", "CriticalTemperature", 
"Density", "Enthalpy", "Entropy", "InternalEnergy", 
"IsobaricHeatCapacity", "IsochoricHeatCapacity", 
"LiquidVaporPhaseBoundary", "MolarDensity", "MolarEnthalpy", 
"MolarEntropy", "MolarInternalEnergy", "MolarIsobaricHeatCapacity", 
"MolarIsochoricHeatCapacity", "MolarSpecificVolume", "Name", "Phase", 
"SolidLiquidPhaseBoundary", "SolidVaporPhaseBoundary", "SoundSpeed", 
"SpecificVolume", "ThermalConductivity", "TriplePointGasDensity", 
"TriplePointLiquidDensity", "TriplePointPressure", 
"TriplePointSolidDensity", "TriplePointTemperature", "Viscosity"} *)
```

But not all of those are functions of temperature or pressure.  There is a list of properties which depend on these parameters in the documentation, but below I just filter them out.

```
propertiesTP = 
  ThermodynamicData["Properties"] // 
   DeleteCases[_?(StringMatchQ[#, 
        "Critical*" | "Triple*" | "*Phase*" | "Name"] &)];

temps = Quantity[Range[0, 99], "DegreesCelsius"];
ListLinePlot[
   Thread[
    {temps,
     ThermodynamicData["Water", #, {"Temperature" -> temps}]}
    ], AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> #, 
   ImageSize -> 250] & /@ propertiesTP
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
density = 
 Table[{i, 
   WolframAlpha[
    StringJoin["Water Density ", ToString[i], 
     " celsius"], {{"Result", 1}, "NumberData"}]}, {i, 1, 99}]

ListPlot[density, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 FrameLabel -> {"Temperature (C)", "Density kg/m3"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Water Density vs Temperature"]
```

[image]