# How to I get a nutrition facts chart from WolframAlpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

When I try just a few items such as

```
WolframAlpha["1 whole wheat tortilla + 2 slices american cheese + 150 g steak + 2 tbsp beans + 150 g white rice"]
```

I get the following nutrition facts table:

[image]

However, when I enter a longer query such as

```
WolframAlpha["1 whole wheat tortilla + 2 slices american cheese + 150 g steak + 2 tbsp beans + 150 g white rice + 100g bell peppers + 200 g chicken breast + 2 slices of whole wheat bread"]
```

I don't actually get a nutrition facts chart as before. Is there a way to force a nutrition facts output every time? Also, is there a way to limit the output pods to only a nutrition facts table, as I don't need any of the other pods?

Answer (score 3):

To get just the nutrition facts for simpler data use:

```
WolframAlpha["1 whole wheat tortilla + 2 slices american cheese + 150 g steak",
{{"NutritionLabelMultiplePlus", 1}, "Content"}]
```

To understand how to get this code [**use this answer as guide**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9545/13).

That other 2nd entry is so complex and long it throws something off in formatting. You can send [**feedback to Wolfram**](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback) about it.

Comment: Feedback for Wolfram|Alpha should be sent to info@wolframalpha.com

Comment: If you can figure out a way to use this, and include TimeConstraint, that'd be the ideal solution. I tried WolframAlpha[query, {{"NutritionLabelMultiplePlus", 1}, "Content"}, 
 TimeConstraint -> 600], but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The longer query is timing out. Set TimeConstraint option to larger value to enable completion. Use IncludePods->"NutritionLabelMultiplePlus" option setting to limit output content.

```
query1 = "1 whole wheat tortilla + 2 slices american cheese + 150 g steak + 2 tbsp beans + 150 g white rice";

query2 = query1 <> 
   " + 100 g bell peppers + 200 g chicken breast + 2 slices of whole wheat bread";

WolframAlpha[query1, IncludePods -> "NutritionLabelMultiplePlus"]

WolframAlpha[query2, IncludePods -> "NutritionLabelMultiplePlus", 
 TimeConstraint -> 60]
```

Comment: Increasing TimeConstraint did not work for me for longer query, - pod was simply not returned. Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked for me. Perhaps you need even more time with your internet connection.

Comment: This also didn't work for me. Using your code results in the following message: "Wolfram|Alpha doesn't know how to interpret your input."