# Historical Exchange Rates via FinancialData

Tags: curated-data, finance

[`FinancialData["name"]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FinancialData.html) and `FinancialData["name", start]` return respectively; the last known price, and the daily closing values for dates from start until the current date, for the financial entity - `"name"`. One of the possible entities quoted is `"Currency exchange rates"` and while the Documentation's claims hold for the first case ...

```
Column[{
DateString[],
FinancialData[{"AUD", "USD"}],
WolframAlpha["AUD/USD", {{"Result", 1}, "Plaintext"},"PodStates" -> {"Result__More accuracy"}],
1/CountryData["Australia", "ExchangeRate"]
}]

(*
"Sat 26 Apr 2014 07:03:11"
0.9274
"$0.9282  (US dollars)"
$0.838801
*)
```

it doesn't appear to for the second ...

```
FinancialData[{"AUD", "USD"}, {2013}]
(* 
 Missing["NotAvailable"]
 *)
```

The Wolfram | Alpha query included above graphs a handful of previous years so *some* historical data can be extracted but clearly not in the systematic, fine-grained way one might expect from using `FinancialData`.

There is no mention of this particular missing data in the Documentation although apparently there can be [periodic issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9540/problem-with-financial-data/9555#9555) with the [data sources](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/note/FinancialDataSourceInformation.html) and while [directly accessing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46760/how-to-request-financial-data-from-yahoos-yql) these sources offers a possible workaround, this only applies if the sources themselves provide API's for this historical data (which *doesn't* appear to be the case for one such source - *Yahoo! Finance*)

The documentation goes on to say:

> `FinancialData`provides gateways to external financial data sources.
>   Its use is     subject to any restrictions associated with those
>   sources, and may require additional licensing.

This is perhaps one such instance although few other claimed currency properties seem to be available and/or relevant (at least with my connection?)

```
With[{props = FinancialData[{"AUD", "USD"}, #] & /@ FinancialData[{"AUD", "USD"}, "Properties"]}, 
StringForm["`1` out of `2` of FinancialData's Currency Exchange properties available", 
Count[props, Except[_Missing | _FinancialData | {_Missing, ___}]],Length@props]]

(*
 4 out of 74 of FinancialData's Currency Exchange properties available
*)
```

Comment: The range of computational data available in Mathematica promises much but not making explicit current scope limitations is IMO unfortunate. Part of the power of the Wolfram Language lies in its generality and uniformity so it's a reasonable expectation that unless notified otherwise this will extend to data sources. Where it does not, either because curation is not yet possible or else subject to further licensing, making these explicit (perhaps graphically and/or through additional licensing instructions) would greatly assist users scoping out potential applications.

Comment: The motivation of accessing this data comes from several recent hunches that the Australian dollar is significantly overvalued (anticipating a fall to ~80c by 2015 for future hunch-judgers) but don't particularly trust my intuition when it comes to predicting notorious currency movements - nor for that matter Australia's Reserve Bank or this country's economists. Whether big data-driven finance models can prove to be any less Sisyphean, Faustian or even King-Cnut-like is debatable but going there would at least appear inadvisable without access to such historical data.

Comment: Indeed both questions seem highly related although they are posed differently. Some of the answers in that question are quite ingenious, but so are the ones provided here by the community. Can they be merged?

Comment: The only problem with a merge is the additional work required to make the answers here make sense for the question there; if the authors do not mind this I will happily perform the merge.

Comment: Bloomberg charges $2k/month per seat to their terminals, and have more than a thousand ppl in R&D.

Comment: I would not mind the merge.

Comment: @alancalvitti I'm not sure Bloomberg's R&D spend alone convinces about any fundamental Forex predictability. That was two years ago. Now however,  it seems the era of [manufactured intuition](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCP7jMXSY2xbc3KCAE0MHQ-A) is upon us..

Comment: @RonaldMonson, nevermind the game of Go - though that's interesting for AI. Compare Bloomberg's thousands of journalists, editors and engineers curating data and building queries that show up as facts and trends, not as predictions.

Comment: @RonaldMonson,  it's great that trees of complexity b^d are being mastered, eg Chess: b=~35, d=~80, vs Go: b=~250, d=~150 ["Mastering the game of Go" Nature Jan 2016]. In real life games are not perfect information and who's to tell how big the trees are, and branch values.

Comment: @alancalvitti The significance of "mastering Go" (beating all human masters) is in my view, epochal (2-0 now). Beyond the chess mastering, this "brute force" seems more nuanced, combining expert rules with reinforcement learning, simulations/play etc -  more humanlike in potentially becoming applicable (nonchalant) to *any* sized trees. But yes, to work many more trees need curating.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get exchange rates from the Federal Reserve using their data download package maker at:- http://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/

See the link for Exchange Rates and International Data.

The package maker produces a download link that can be used as shown.

```
startdate = "12/31/1995";
enddate = DateString[{"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "Year"}];

fxdownload = Import@StringJoin[
    "http://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Output.aspx?rel=H10&series=91c3fa18b51a37d6c8bb96f5263c9409&lastObs=&from=",
    startdate, "&to=", enddate,
    "&filetype=csv&label=include&layout=seriescolumn"];
fxdata = Drop[fxdownload, 6];
datelistfx = Cases[fxdata, {_, _?NumberQ}];
datelistfx[[All, 1]] = Join[ToExpression@StringSplit[#, "-"],
      {0, 0, 0.}] & /@ datelistfx[[All, 1]];

DateListPlot[datelistfx, Joined -> True,
 PlotLabel -> StringJoin["Daily AUD/USD from ",
   DateString[datelistfx[[1, 1]], {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}], " to ",
   DateString[datelistfx[[-1, 1]], {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Mathematica 10 has a way to do this: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/dimensional-variables/convert-currencies-using-historical-exchange-rates.html

The relevant new functions in Mathematica 10 are [`DatedUnit[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DatedUnit.html) and [`InflationAdjust[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InflationAdjust.html). If I wanted to convert 1 USD to EUR using the January 1, 2015 exchange rate, for example, I would execute:

```
InflationAdjust[
  Quantity[1, DatedUnit["USDollars", {2015, 1, 1}]],
  DatedUnit["Euros", {2015, 1, 1}]
]
```

Then I could run [`QuantityMagnitude[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityMagnitude.html) on the result to get just the numeric value.

Answer (score 9):

Mathematica's `FinancialData` (and the economic data in `CountryData`, for that matter) promise much but for serious work you are often better off going to other sources. That way you are more likely to get more detailed metadata so you know what you re looking at.

In your specific case you are better off going to the Reserve Bank of Australia’s web site, and using `Import` to extract their historical data in XLS format: http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/hist-exchange-rates/index.html

While you are there, have a look at http://www.rba.gov.au/publications/rdp/2011/2011-05.html and http://www.rba.gov.au/foi/disclosure-log/rbafoi-131412.html

Comment: Wow! Those Aussies know their job!:)

Answer (score 8):

You also can use:

[Financial data from Quandl in Wolfram Language using QuandlLink](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/604692)

```
<< QuandlLink`

AUDvsUSDrates = QuandlFinancialData["CURRFX/AUDUSD",
    startDate -> "1995-1-1", endDate -> "2015-5-1"];

DateListPlot[Transpose[{#[[All, 1]], #[[All, 2, 1]]} &@Rest[AUDvsUSDrates]], 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You may derive data from `WolframAlfa` request (10Y period). Copy the Pod Plot (de facto `Graphics`) and get `InputForm`:
[image]

Let's give the name `rate` to the result. We are looking for `rate[[1, 2, 1, ;;-3]]` part of data, which is the list with each element of the form `{AbsoluteTime, exchange_rate * 100}`. Note that I deleted last 3 elements (`;;-3`).

So, we just need to convert `AbsoluteTime` to `DateList` and adjust exchange rates:

```
dates = (DateList /@ rate[[1, 2, 1, ;; -3, 1]])[[;; , 1 ;; 3]];
exchange = rate[[1, 2, 1, ;; -3, 2]]/100;

data = Thread[{dates, exchange}]
```

To check the data:

```
DateListPlot[data]
```

[image]

I hope that helps.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I am fine with the idea but not familiar with merge technique, so please feel free to do whatever is needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extended comment rather than an answer.

There is some limited statistical data available by calling WolframAlpha. You have a choice of several formats for this data.

```
WolframAlpha["FinancialData[{\"AUD\",\"USD\"},{2013}]", {{"History", 1}, 
  "FormattedData"}, PodStates -> {"History__Last 10 years"}]
```

[image]

```
WolframAlpha["FinancialData[{\"AUD\",\"USD\"},{2013}]", {{"History", 1}, 
  "ComputableData"}, PodStates -> {"History__Last 10 years"}]

(*  {Missing["NotAvailable"], {{"10-year  minimum", 
   Quantity[1825.68, "AustralianDollars"]}, {"10-year  maximum", 
   Quantity[3335.82, "AustralianDollars"]}, {"10-year  average", 
   Quantity[2312.59, "AustralianDollars"]}}}  *)

WolframAlpha["FinancialData[{\"AUD\",\"USD\"},{2013}]", {{"History", 1}, 
  "QuantityData"}, PodStates -> {"History__Last 10 years"}]

(*  {Quantity[1825.68, "AustralianDollars"], 
 Quantity[3335.82, "AustralianDollars"], 
 Quantity[2312.59, "AustralianDollars"]}  *)

WolframAlpha["FinancialData[{\"AUD\",\"USD\"},{2013}]", {{"History", 1}, 
  "NumberData"}, PodStates -> {"History__Last 10 years"}]

(*  {1825.68, 3335.82, 2312.59}  *)
```