# Difference between free-form input via WolframAlpha[] and CTRL+=

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, natural-language, free-form-input

WolframAlpha["query"] - https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html

Free-form input - https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/EnterFreeFormInput.html

For example:

```
WolframAlpha["Solve[x^2+5x+6==0, x]"]
```

and

`=` and after

```
Solve[x^2+5x+6==0, x]
```

Both have have pretty similar output (cannot include it here because of sophisticated formatting).

**Questions:**

1. Does the both use WolframAlpha?
2. Is there any difference between them? If yes, what is the difference?

Comment: They both should be using wolfram alpha as of version 8. See "With the new Mathematica 8, you can access the Wolfram|Alpha engine directly from within Mathematica. Inside a Mathematica notebook document, just type == at the beginning of a line; you’ll get an orange Spikey icon indicating that Mathematica is ready to perform a Wolfram|Alpha query. "  http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2010/12/06/mathematica-becomes-a-wolframalpha-interface/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the summary from [original M8 release page](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/free-form-linguistic-input/):

[image]

This guide should also be useful: [Free-Form & External Input](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FreeFormAndExternalInput.html). While both things you mentioned are a part of integration of Wolfram|Alpha (W|A) and Wolfram Language (WL), the difference is in the **interface**, **goal** and type of **output** they give you. Free-form input (FFI) via `CTRL+=` is great, for example, for quick-typing of FFI and its quick automatic conversion into [entities](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/KnowledgeRepresentationAndAccess.html), [units](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Units.html), and other [Wolfram Knowledgebase](https://www.wolfram.com/knowledgebase/) things. Hence `CTRL+=` is great for quick discovering of various numerous built-in quantities and other bits of knowledge that is so large it is very hard to grasp via some general overview. `CTRL+=` attempts to give the best semantic interpretation of the specified free-form string as a [WL expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html) and can be used inside other WL expressions. In that sense it is a quick-interface embodiment of its programatic form [SemanticInterpretation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticInterpretation.html) (do not confuse with [Interpreter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpreter.html), which is another wonderful related function working a bit differently). As they seek a WL expression as an output you can quickly test the boundaries and see the difference with `WolframAlpha[...]` function. For instance, try this out:

```
In[]:=SemanticInterpretation["tell me a joke"]
Out[]=$Failed
```

and similarly:

[image]

As expected no WL expression form is found as there is none to find. On the other hand behold

[image]

This works as full W|A output is returned. `WolframAlpha[...]` interface embodiment is double-equal tap:

[image]

`WolframAlpha[...]` is great for [controlled programmatic yield](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DataFormatsInWolframAlpha.html) of various outputs, for instance

```
data= WolframAlpha["sun spots",
{{"SunspotsFullTimeSeries:SpaceWeatherData",1},"TimeSeriesData"}];
DateListPlot[data]
```

[image]

the code for which is automatically generated as explained [HERE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9545/13)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for great answer! Also "SemanticInterpretation" link (or maybe it should be inline code?) is broken.

Comment: @vasili111 thank you, fixed thee link.